# react native firebase cloud functions with geofirestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-firebase, geofirestore

**What i want to do:**

I am fairly new to how cloud function work, just need help understanding what i am doing wrong.

Need to request locations from firestore to react native client through firebase cloud functions.

I tried something similar on the client side but need to have the same results when making request with cloud functions.

**client code:**

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const lat = 45.78768768
const lng = -67.56457667
const httpsCallable = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('findLocations');
let collection = this.props.navigation.state.params.document; //collection name eg hotels
        const test = {
            db: collection.name,
            coordinates: {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude:lng
            }
        }

        httpsCallable({
             request: test })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                console.long(data);
                 this.setState({ data: data });
            })
            .catch((httpsError) => {
                console.log(httpsError.code); // invalid-argument
                console.log(httpsError.message); // Your error message goes here
            });
```

**cloud Function:**

```
const admin = require('./node_modules/firebase-admin');
const firebase = require('./node_modules/firebase');
const { GeoCollectionReference, GeoFirestore, GeoQuery, GeoQuerySnapshot } = require('./node_modules/geofirestore');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'app-url',
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(firestore);
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);

exports.findLocations = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

    if (!data.request) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'invalid-argument', // code
            'Your error message goes here', // message
        );
    } else {
        let locations = [];
        const geocollection = geofirestore.collection(data.db);
        geocollection
            .limit(20)
            .near({
                center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(data.latitude, data.longitude),
                radius: 100,
            })
            .get()
            .then((GeoQuerySnapshot) => {
                GeoQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    return locations.push(doc.data());
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
            });
    }

    return { locations: locations };
});
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your question. You say "need help understanding what i am doing wrong" - but you don't explain what you are getting right now and why it is wrong?

Comment: i just get back internal errors, and do not know what they mean.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you, if you are not sharing the exact errors?

Comment: no literally that is the error im getting "Internal error", ive tried to debug but its been near impossible to find the exact issue